# How Do I add only TIME in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I need to do a calculation for my crystal report.

In report, there will be Times(in Hour:Min:Sec)like this..

00:12:34

00:52:12

23:19:56

and so on..

I need to add them together so that..results will be

Hr:min:ss

Hr may be more than 100..

but can't change to day

How to achieve that?

Thanks a lot..

Comment: In what form the time will be? DateTime or strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the [TimeSpan.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx) method like this.

```
var t1 = TimeSpan.Parse("00:12:34");
var t2 = TimeSpan.Parse("00:52:12");
var t3 = TimeSpan.Parse("23:19:56");

var result = t1 + t2 + t3

Console.WriteLine("Total time is {0} Hours {1} Mins {2} secs", 
result.Days * 24 + result.Hours, result.Minutes, results.Seconds);
```

Comment: good idea.. thanks for that..
but in ur ans, can i combine the Days and hours and show them together as Hours..?
like 1 Day, 1 Hr as 25 Hours??

Comment: yes you can get Days from `TimeSpan` object like `result.Days`

Comment: william: You want `(int)result.TotalHours`.

Comment: May b I didn't make it very clear.. What I wanna ask is..
I dun want days..
just hours..
according to above example,
the results should b "24:24:42"
not 1 day, "00:24:42"

Comment: No, TimeSpan can't have more than 23 hours & 59 minutes & 59 seconds etc.  But it's easy to say `result.Days * 24 + result.Hours`

Answer (score 0):

It you are getting hh:mm:ss only then this will be easy:

```
hh x 60 x 60 + mm x 60 + ss
```

and then get hours, mins and seconds from it.

If you are getting `DateTime` object then you can get hours, mins and convert them to seconds and use same technique as above.

Comment: yea.. that's one idea..
get the total sec of everything and add them up together..
after that.. divided back to hour, min, second.
I have tried that.. the coding is too long.. 
so just asking any better idea..??
sth like shortcut?